# Jest Mock Globally From a Node Module

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing a series of Node modules that require a bunch of common Jest mocks to be setup before I can write unit tests.
I am trying to refactor the unit test setup into a separate module so I can avoid rewriting the setup each time.
The problem is that when I import the following code as a module it no longer mocks the other libraries, while it works just fine when the mocks are set up in a utility file.

Working Code:

```
jest.mock('@actions/core')
jest.mock('@actions/github')
const { GitHub, context} = require('@actions/github')
const core = require('@actions/core')

GitHub.mockImplementation(() => {
return {
    {
        repos: {
            getContents: jest.fn()
        }
    }
}
}
module.exports = { core, GitHub, context }
```

I keep this in a `utils.js` file next to my test files and import it like `const { core, GitHub, context } = require('./utils.js')`  and everything mocks as I expect.  I can run `expect().toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` and get the numbers I expect.

The problem appears when I move `utils.js`  to another module and require it.

I know that at [bottom of the jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) it says "...Another file that imports the module will get the original implementation even if it runs after the test file that mocks the module."  But I am seeing this work inconsistently with the external file.

Anyone know how to get mocking setup in external modules?